# Can someone explain Euclid's Book 1 Definition 7, 8, and 9?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-history

7. A plane surface is a surface which lies evenly with the straight lines on itself.
8. A plane angle is the inclination to one another of two lines in a plane which meet one another and do not lie in a straight line.
9. And when the lines containing the angle are straight, the angle is called rectilineal.

Also, define rectilineal.
If possible provide a picture.

(Mainly 8 and 9).
I think 8 is a normal angle and 9 seems like a straight line, but I'm not sure.

- thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the entire *Euclid's Elements* on [this website](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/bookI.html). Every topic is a clickable link which provides diagrams.

On the link of [definition $8$](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/defI8.html), the following is made clear. Lines can be straight or curved (e.g., a circular arc). When both the arms of an angle are straight lines, we have a *rectilinear angle*.

When a curve and a straight line 'contain' an angle e.g., the angle formed between a circle and its tangent at a point, the term *horn angle* is used.

The phrase *rectilinear* is used for a figure made of straight lines only. For example, a polygon is rectilinear means it all of its sides are straight lines, none is curved.

Comment: ahh so def: 8 defines angles broadly;

whereas def: 9, defines angles formed by straight lines intersecting(rectilinear), which are the conventional angles we deal with in normal figures i.e. triangle, rectangle...

Thanks so much! reading definition 9 alone led to my confusion.

Comment: Correct. The concepts of line, angle, surface etc are all defined broadly. Besides plane angles, there are also dihedral and trihedral angles.